# What is required to reset graphics card LUTs?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

What is required to reset any internal LUT tables on a graphics card? The card in question is an NVIDIA 540M with Optimus.

After a very bizarre color mixup on a brand-new Dell XPS 15 L502X (while attempting to calibrate the B+RGLED display), I decided to simply do a factory restore as the quickest method of starting over. It had only been out of the box a few hours anyway.

Rebooted and did the Dell factory restore.

**Question:** Are the gfx card's LUT reset on reboot? Could any existing values have been maintained during the reset, since the machine's battery was not actually removed?